# Android app deployed by Hockeyapp not connecting to internet

Tags: android, xamarin, hockeyapp

I have an simple android app written using Xamarin.
At start up time it tries to do certain REST calls to an backend.
This works fine in my emulator and when I usb debug on my S7.
But when I try to deploy using hockeyapp every single api call seems to fail.

I have looked through the manifest files, and the INTERNET permission is set.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error when it fails?

Comment: It seeems that the HTTPGet messages are working but not HTTPPost.
Is there some kind of encoding that is changed?

Comment: Just saw a similar thread where GET worked and POST did not. That had to do with HTTPS urls and self-signed certs. Have you tested the app in release mode on an emulator or only in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, now that i tried the release build cant connect neither.
And when I deployed debug build using hockeyapp it works.
Question is how to fix this? We are not using any HTTPS urls only plain http.

Comment: Is there any difference between the release URLs and the debug URLs? What about differences between your android project properties in debug and release?

Comment: Found the error. was linking both sdk and user libs in release. when just linking to sdk it works like a charm.

Comment: Good stuff! Glad you figured it out